# How to obtain a sequence of screenshots of the cursor's area in near-real-time in a WPF program?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am building a Digital Colorimeter WPF program, but I have a quite annoying problem: I don't know how to capture an area of the screen with the cursor's position at the center in near-real-time sequence, i.e. every 10 milliseconds.

I have obtained a method to do this, it works if I associate a Button click event to it, but I need to do it in a Thread that cycles every 10 ms.

Here you have the code that I already created:

**MainWindow**, with the main ViewModel:

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public AppViewModel ViewModel { get; set; } = new AppViewModel();
    public static MainWindow Current;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Current = this;
        this.DataContext = ViewModel;
        // ...
    }
}
```

**HomePage**, to which I navigate, starting immediately the Thread (the Win32Point is a struct equal to Point, but with X and Y as Int32 instead of doubles):

```
public partial class HomePage : Page
{
    Thread ThCursor;
    public AppViewModel ViewModel => MainWindow.Current.ViewModel;
    public HomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = ViewModel;
        ThCursor = new Thread(TaskMain);
        ThCursor.Start();
    }

    private void TaskMain()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Win32Point point = new Win32Point();
            point = ViewModel.GetCursorPosition();


            ViewModel.CursorPoint = new Win32Point() { X = point.X, Y = point.Y };

            // ...

            ViewModel.SourceImage = ViewModel.GetScreenBitmap(ViewModel.CursorPoint, 10);  
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModel.SourceImage = ViewModel.GetScreenBitmap(ViewModel.CursorPoint, 10);
    }
}
```

...and the main **ViewModel** itself (the BaseBind class is a little class that has INotifyPropertyChanged interface):

```
public class AppViewModel : BaseBind
{
    #region DLL
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr window);
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern uint GetPixel(IntPtr dc, int x, int y);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int ReleaseDC(IntPtr window, IntPtr dc);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool GetCursorPos(ref Win32Point lpPoint);
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern int BitBlt(IntPtr hDC, int x, int y, int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hSrcDC, int xSrc, int ySrc, int dwRop);

    IntPtr desk;
    IntPtr dc;

    #endregion

    public AppViewModel()
    {
        desk = GetDesktopWindow();
        dc = GetWindowDC(desk);

        CursorPoint = new Win32Point() { X = 200, Y = 200 };

        // ...

        SourceImage = null; //GetScreenBitmap(new Win32Point() { X = 0, Y = 0 }, 40);
    }

    private Win32Point cursorPoint;
    public Win32Point CursorPoint{
        get { return cursorPoint; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref cursorPoint, value);
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private BitmapSource sourceImage;
    public BitmapSource SourceImage
    {
        get { return sourceImage; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref sourceImage, value);
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public Win32Point GetCursorPosition()
    {
        Win32Point point = new Win32Point();
        GetCursorPos(ref point);
        return point;
    }

    // ...

    public BitmapSource GetScreenBitmap(Win32Point point, int size)
    {
        var bm = new Bitmap(size, size, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        var bmpGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
        bmpGraphics.CopyFromScreen(point.X - (size/2), point.Y - (size/2), 0, 0, bm.Size);
        var bmpS = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(bm.GetHbitmap(), IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        return bmpS;
    }
```

Last, but not least, the **HomePage.xaml**:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    // ...

    <Button x:Name="Button1" Margin="5" Content="Click" Click="Button1_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

    <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="#FFE62020" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="1">
        <Image Source="{Binding SourceImage, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="40" Height="40"/>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Tha's it, I cut off every thing that doesn't help in this question.
The function

> ViewModel.GetScreenBitmap

works really well with a single click event, but the entire app crashes when I try to execute it in the HomePage's thread... perhaps it is too heavy to produce hundreds of bitmaps per seconds?
I need to create some sort of "image" of the area where the cursor is in near-real-time, like in the Digital Colorimeter from MacOS:

[image]

I really would appreciate your help.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having a new memory leak every 10 ms actually.

From Bitmap.GetHbitmap() documentation :

> You are responsible for calling the GDI DeleteObject method to free the memory used by the GDI bitmap object.

You also have a code snippet in the documentation to call DeleteObject on the IntPtr :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dz311e4(v=vs.110).aspx

```
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);

    public BitmapSource GetScreenBitmap(Win32Point point, int size)
    {
        var bm = new Bitmap(size, size, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        var bmpGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
        bmpGraphics.CopyFromScreen(point.X - (size / 2), point.Y - (size / 2), 0, 0, bm.Size);
        IntPtr hBitmap = bm.GetHbitmap();
        var bmpS = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(hBitmap, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        DeleteObject(hBitmap);
        return bmpS;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I'm still getting the same error after crashing:

Comment: It even says: it is necessary to create a DependencySource in the same thread of the DependencyObject.    What does it mean?

Comment: You can't update GUI from a different thread than Main UI thread, change your code in TaskMain() that is updating UI, maybe use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke for instance. There are many discussions on SO on this issue.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me to solve this question: using the Dispathcer.BeginInvoke and setting the Thread.Sleep(20), now it just works.   There's only one little problem left: image refreshing rate slows down when the cursor is over the app's window and then runs smooth when the cursor is elsewhere... how could this happen?